# Name space error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I misspelled the name space in my yo configuration. I have deleted and corrected it, but it seems like the name space still persists ie.

> Pros-MacBook-Pro:tutorial-network Santi$ composer archive create -t
>   dir -n . Creating Business Network Archive
>
> Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition   Input
>   directory: /Users/pro/~fabric-tools/tutorial-network
>   TypeNotFoundException: Namespace is not defined for type
>   org.acne.biznet.Trade Command failed

org.acne.biznet.Trade is the error. Should be 'acme'

Is this what is causing the error? Will appreciate pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. In my lib/logic.js file, I had a misspelling :

```
/**
 * Track the trade of a commodituy from one trader to another
 * @param {org.acne.biznet.Trade} trade # here
 * @transaction
 */
```

Changing it to `@param {org.acme.biznet.Trade}` trade resolved it.